# Proving that $\gamma = \int_{0}^{1} \!\!\int_{0}^{1} \!\frac{x - 1}{(1 - x y) \log(x y)} \, \mathrm{d}{x} \, \mathrm{d}{y} $.

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, improper-integrals

In 2005, J. Sondow found a surprising formula for the Euler-Mascheroni constant $ \gamma $. The formula is
$$
  \gamma
= \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x - 1}{(1 - x y) \log(x y)}
  ~ \mathrm{d}{x} ~ \mathrm{d}{y}.
$$
Now, the definition of $ \gamma $ is
$$
\gamma
\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[ \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} - \log(n) \right].
$$
I have tried using the geometric series
$$
\frac{1}{1 - x y} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^{n} y^{n}
$$
to obtain a proof, but it would not work. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main
page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730)
for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20):

This$\require{autoload-all}$ post outlines exactly how you would use the geometric series to reach the series that the original post has given. The beauty of this method lies in it's generalizations which I have placed several examples of in my post. If you want to see an easier method of finding the answer to the specific integral, see my other answer.

I will begin by first defining the exponential integral and then proving some lemmas which will assist in the proof. We write ${\operatorname{Ei}(x)}$ for the exponential integral and it is defined as follows.

$$\operatorname{Ei}(x) = -\int_{-x}^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t$$

I will use the following properties (hover over each statement for reasoning):

$$\mathtip{\lim_{x\to -\infty}  \operatorname{Ei}(x) = 0}{\text{Clear from the definition of } \operatorname{Ei}(x).} \tag{1a}$$

$$\mathtip{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \operatorname{Ei}(x)  = \frac{e^x}{x}}{\text{Clear from the definition of } \operatorname{Ei}(x).} \tag{1b}$$

$$\mathtip{\int\operatorname{Ei}(x)\, \mathrm{d}x = x\operatorname{Ei}(x) – e^x + C}{\text{Integrate by parts or take the derivative of the right hand side.}{}} \tag{1c}$$

$$\mathtip{\int \operatorname{Ei}(x)e^{\alpha x}\, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{e^{\alpha x}\operatorname{Ei}(x) -\operatorname{Ei}((\alpha+1)x)}{\alpha} + C}{\text{Integrate by parts or take the derivative of the right hand side.}{}} \tag{1d}$$

I will begin with two preliminary lemmas.

Lemma $1$:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{\log(ax)} \mathrm{d}x = a^{-n-1}\operatorname{Ei}((n+1)\log(a)) \tag{2}$$

$$
\toggle{ 
\enclose{roundedbox}{\text{ Click to Reveal Proof }}
}{
\boxed{\text{Substitute } -\log(ax) = u}\\[.2cm]
\int_{\infty}^{-\log(a)}-\frac{(e^u/a)^{n+1}}{u} \mathrm{d}u\\[.2cm]
\boxed{\text{Simplify and use properties of integration}}\\[.2cm]
\int_{-\log(a)}^{\infty}a^{-n-1}\frac{e^{(n+1)u}}{u} \mathrm{d}u\\[.2cm]
\boxed{\text{Substitute }t = (n+1)u\text{ and then evaluate using the definition of }\operatorname{Ei}(x).}\\[.2cm]
\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{\log(ax)} \mathrm{d}x = a^{-n-1}\operatorname{Ei}((n+1)\log(a))\\
\enclose{roundedbox}{\text{ Click to Close Proof}}}\endtoggle
$$

Lemma $2 $ (very significant):

$$\int_0^1 \dfrac{\operatorname{Ei}(a\log(y))}{y^n} \mathrm{d}y =  \lim_{n_0\to n}  \frac{1}{n_0-1}\log\left(1+\frac{1-n_0}{a}\right) \tag{3}$$

Proof is located at the bottom of the post. The limit must be used for the case $n = 1$.

Now to evaluate the integral:

$$ \begin{align} I &=  \int_{0}^{1}\!\!\int_{0}^{1}\!\dfrac{x-1}{(1 – xy)\log(xy)}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \\ &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\!\!\int_{0}^{1}\!\sum_{k=0}^n \left[\frac{x^{k+1}y^k}{\log(xy)} - \frac{x^{k}y^k}{\log(xy)}\right]\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \end{align}$$

Using $(2)$:

$$I =  \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left[\frac{\operatorname{Ei}((k+2)\log(y))}{y^2}- \frac{\operatorname{Ei}((k+1)\log(y))}{y}\right] \mathrm{d}y$$

Using $(3)$:

$$I =  \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \left[\log\left(1-\frac{1}{k+2}\right)+\frac{1}{k+1}\right]$$

Finally:

$$\begin{align}I &=  \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \left[\log\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)+\frac{1}{k}\right]\\
&=  \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \left[\log(k)-\log(k+1)+\frac{1}{k}\right]\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k} - \log(n)\end{align}$$

---

$\LARGE \text{Generalizations:}$

This approach is not very good for the simple integral given in the original post but it is a very strong approach in general. In the proof of Lemma 2, we were able to develop a general formula for $I_n$. Using the same technique, it is possible to evaluate more complicated integrals such as

$$\int_{0}^{1}\!\!\int_{0}^{1}\!\dfrac{(x-1)^2}{(1 – xy)\log(xy)}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = \log(\sqrt{2}) - \gamma$$

In fact, if we let $P(x)$ be any polynomial, we can find a closed form for

$$\int_{0}^{1}\!\!\int_{0}^{1}\!\dfrac{(x-1)P(x)}{(1 – xy)\log(xy)}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$

The factor of $(x-1)$ exists to ensure the numerator goes to zero as $x \to 1$. In general, we can do more than just polynomials in $x$. Here are some of the more interesting results that can be obtained

$$\int_{0}^{1}\!\!\int_{0}^{1}\!\dfrac{\sqrt{x}(x-1)}{(1 – xy)\log(xy)}\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = \frac{1}{3} (\log (36)-2 \log (\pi ))$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\!\!\int_{0}^{1}\!\dfrac{x^3+9x^2-11x+1}{(1 – xy)\log(xy)}\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y =\log(16)+\frac{\log(3)}{3}+\frac{5\log(2)}{6} - \gamma\\$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\!\!\int_{0}^{1}\!\dfrac{\sqrt[4]{y}\sqrt{x}(1-x)}{(1 – xy)\log(xy)}\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y =\frac{4}{5} \!\left(\log (24)-2 \log (\pi )+4 \log \left(\Gamma (5/4)\right)\right)$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\!\!\int_{0}^{1}\!\dfrac{y^{\pi}(x-1)}{(1 – xy)\log(xy)}\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = \frac{\log (\pi )+\log \left(\left(-6+11 \pi -6 \pi ^2+\pi ^3\right) \Gamma (-3+\pi )\right)}{(\pi -1) \pi }$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\!\!\int_{0}^{1}\!\dfrac{x^{\pi}(x-1)}{(1 – xy)\log(xy)}\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = -\frac{\log (\pi -3)-\pi  \log (1+\pi )+\log \left(\pi  \left(2-3 \pi +\pi ^2\right) \Gamma (-3+\pi )\right)}{\pi  (1+\pi )}$$

The most significant one (in my opinion) is this one:

$$\boxed{\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\!\!\int_{0}^{1}\!\dfrac{x^{n}y^{n}(x-1)}{(1 – xy)\log(xy)}\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = \log(1+n)-\psi(1+n)}$$

This is not only a beautiful formula but it allows us to say that the integral of the original question can be easily shown to be $-\psi(1) = \gamma$. In this case, $\psi$ is the [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function). See my other answer for a quick route to developing this formula.

---

Here is the proof of Lemma 2. If you don't understand a step, hover over the equations. Note that $a+1>n$. The final generalization of $I_n$ is very useful for the generalization I later prove.

$$\begin{align}I_n &= \int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Ei}(a \log (y))}{y^n} \mathrm{d}y\\[.3cm]
 &\mathtip{= \int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{\operatorname{Ei}(u)}{e^{n\cdot u/a}}\frac{e^{u/a}}{a} \mathrm{d}u}{\text{Substitute } u = a\log(y). \text{ and then integrate using property (1d)}}\\[.3cm]
&\mathtip{= \left. \frac{e^{(1-n)u/a}\operatorname{Ei}(u)-\operatorname{Ei}((a+1-n)u/a)}{1-n} \right|_{-\infty}^{\,0}}{\text{Integrate using property (1d)}.}\\[.2cm]
&\mathtip{=\left. \frac{y^{1-n}\operatorname{Ei}(a\log(y))-\operatorname{Ei}((a+1-n)\log(y))}{1-n} \right|_{\,0}^{\,1}}{\text{Substitute back in for }y.}
\end{align}$$
To show that $I_1 = -1/a$ simply take the limit as $n \to 1$ using L'Hopital's rule and then evaluate. To find $I_n$ for $n > 1$ consider the following limits.

$$\begin{align}
\text{Lower Limit} &= \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y^{1-n}\operatorname{Ei}(a\log(y))-\operatorname{Ei}((a+1-n)\log(y))}{1-n} \\[.3cm]
&\mathtip{=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\operatorname{Ei}(a\log(y))-y^{n-1}\operatorname{Ei}((a+1-n)\log(y))}{(1-n)y^{1-n}}}{\text{Re-arrange terms}.} \\[.3cm]
&\mathtip{\!\overset{\rm{L'H}}{=} \lim_{y\to 0}-\frac{\operatorname{Ei}((a+1-n)\log(y))}{(1-n)}}{\text{Apply L'Hopitals rule using (1b)}.}\\[.3cm]
&\mathtip{= 0.}{\text{Evaluate using (1d)}.}
\end{align}$$

$$\text{Upper Limit} = \lim_{y\to 1}\frac{y^{1-n}\operatorname{Ei}(a\log(y))-\operatorname{Ei}((a+1-n)\log(y))}{1-n}$$

The upper limit is trivial with a simple Taylor series expansion. The upper limit is equal to $$\dfrac{\log(a) - \log(a+1-n)}{1-n}$$ With this,

$$\begin{align}I_n &= \frac{1}{n-1}\log\left(1+\frac{1-n}{a}\right) \\
I_1 &= -\frac{1}{a} \\ I_2 &= \log\left(1-\frac{1}{a}\right)\end{align}$$

This completes the proof of lemma 2.

It is worth noting that $I_1$ can be computed by taking the limit of $I_n$ as $n \to 1$. Furthermore, the above analysis did not depend on $n$ being an integer or being positive. This means that we can write for any $n \in \mathbb{R}$

$$I_n = \lim_{n_0\to n}  \frac{1}{n_0-1}\log\left(1+\frac{1-n_0}{a}\right)$$

Comment: Also I like your solution. Contributes significantly in this matter.

Comment: @Mathsource Note that two of the integrals are easier written using $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$  as $$\int_{0}^{1}\!\!\int_{0}^{1}\!\dfrac{y^{\pi}(x-1)}{(1 – xy)\log(xy)}\,dxdy = \frac{ \log ( \Gamma (\pi+1 ))}{ \pi(\pi -1) }$$


 $$\int_{0}^{1}\!\!\int_{0}^{1}\!\dfrac{x^{\pi}(x-1)}{(1 – xy)\log(xy)}\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = \frac{ \pi  \log (\pi+1 )-\log ( \Gamma (\pi+1 )) }{\pi (\pi+1)}$$ (and, as may be expected, replacing $\pi$ by $\frac12$ yields consistently $$\int_{0}^{1}\!\!\int_{0}^{1}\!\dfrac{\sqrt{x}(x-1)}{(1 – xy)\log(xy)}dxdy = \frac23 (\log (6)-\log (\pi ))$$

Answer (score 19):

Here is an approach that reduces to a single integral:

Notice that:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{(1-xy)\ln(xy)}dy=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{(1-xy)\ln(xy)}d(xy)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{(1-t)\ln t}dt......(1)$$

So
$$I =\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x-1}{(1-xy)\ln(xy)}dxdy=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\int_{0}^{1-\epsilon}\frac{x-1}{x}\left[\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{(1-t)\ln t}dt\right]dx.$$

Integrating by parts,

$$I =\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\left[(x-\ln x)\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{(1-t)\ln t}dt\Big|_{0}^{1-\epsilon}-\int_{0}^{1-\epsilon}\frac{x-\ln x}{(1-x)\ln x}dx\right]= \\ \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\left[[1-\epsilon-\ln(1-\epsilon)]\int_{0}^{1-\epsilon}\frac{1}{(1-x)\ln x}dx-\int_{0}^{1-\epsilon}\frac{x-\ln x}{(1-x)\ln x}dx\right]= \\\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\left[-[\epsilon+\ln(1-\epsilon)]\int_{0}^{1-\epsilon}\frac{1}{(1-x)\ln x}dx+\int_{0}^{1-\epsilon}\left[\frac1{1-x}+\frac1{\ln x}\right]dx\right]=\int_{0}^{1}\left[\frac1{1-x}+\frac1{\ln x}\right]dx = \gamma,$$

where the last single-integral representation of $\gamma$ is well known.

Comment: A very clever solution!

Comment: Thank you very much. It took me a while to understand the transformation of the double integral in simple integral. The remaining solution is routine.

Comment: I think your technique will serve to show that $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x - 1}{(1 + xy)\log(xy)}dxdy = \log(\frac{4}{\pi})$.

Comment: @Berrick Fillmore: Thanks

Comment: @MathFacts: As an improper integral we should set lower limit to $\delta$ and take limit as $\delta \rightarrow 0$.  The lower boundary term should vanish.

Comment: @RRL It also took me sometime to figure the nice trick you used.  I added an intermediate step (1) in your solution so that this nice trick can be revealed explicitly.  Best

Comment: @mike: Its better not to write $\int_{0}^{1}1/[(1-x) \ln x] dx$ by itself because it diverges, but if the upper limit is $1-\epsilon$ and the two integrals are added, then the result converges to $\gamma$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$

Comment: In the first integral, how can the variable that is integrated with respect to be in the bound of integration ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas: I am evaluating the double integral as an iterated integral. The variable of integration is $y$ and $x$ is a constant for the purpose of evaluating the inner integral, which I show first.  Here we use the change of variables $y = t/x$.

Answer (score 11):

I feel like I must submit another answer to this question as I have found a much simpler solution.

Let $$I'(n) = \int_0^1\!\!\int_0^1 \frac{x^ny^n(x-1)}{1-xy} \,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$

Using the geometric series, integrating, and then using partial fractions

$$\begin{align}I'(n) &= \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{N}-\frac{1}{(k+n)(1+k+n)^2}\\
&= \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{N} \frac{1}{k+n+1}-\frac{1}{k+n} +  \sum_{k=0}^{N} \frac{1}{(k+n+1)^2}
\end{align}$$

The first sum telescopes and the second one can be evaluated using the [polygamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html). We have that

$$\psi^{(n)}(z) = \frac{\mathrm d^{n+1}}{\mathrm dz^{n+1}}\log \Gamma(z)= (-1)^{n+1}n! \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z+k)^{n+1}}$$

Use this to find and expression for $I'(n)$ and then integrate with respect to $n$.

$$I'(n) =\int_0^1\!\!\int_0^1 \frac{x^ny^n(x-1)}{1-xy} \,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = \frac{1}{n+1} - \psi^{(1)}(n+1) $$

$$I(n) = \int_0^1\!\!\int_0^1 \frac{x^ny^n(x-1)}{(1-xy)\log(xy)} \,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = \log(n+1) - \psi(n+1) $$

$$\boxed{\displaystyle I(0) = \int_0^1\!\!\int_0^1 \frac{x-1}{(1-xy)\log(xy)} \,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = - \psi(1)  = \gamma}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{x - 1 \over \pars{1 - xy}
\ln\pars{xy}}\,\dd x\,\dd y}} =
\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over y^{2}}\int_{0}^{1}{xy - y \over \pars{1 - xy}
\ln\pars{xy}}\,y\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over y^{2}}\int_{0}^{y}{x - y \over \pars{1 - x}
\ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x\,\dd y =
\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over \pars{1 - x}
\ln\pars{x}}\int_{x}^{1}{x - y \over y^{2}}\,\dd y\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over \pars{1 - x}
\ln\pars{x}}\bracks{1 - x + \ln\pars{x}}\dd x =
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x + \ln\pars{x} \over 1 - x}
\overbrace{\bracks{-\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{t}\,\dd t}}
^{\ds{1 \over \ln\pars{x}}}\ \dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{t + 1} - x^{t} - x^{t}\ln\pars{x} \over 1 - x}
\,\dd x\,\dd t\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{%
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{t + 1} - x^{t} - x^{t}\ln\pars{x} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}} =
\left.\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{t + 1}\mu - x^{t}\mu -
x^{t}\pars{x^{\mu} - 1} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 0}
\\[5mm] = &\
\partiald{}{\mu}\bracks{%
\mu\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{t} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x -
\mu\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{t + 1} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x +
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{t + \mu} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{t} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}_{\ \mu\ =\ 0}
\\[5mm] = &\
\Psi\pars{t + 1} - \Psi\pars{t + 2} + \Psi\, '\pars{t + 1} =
-\,{1 \over t + 1} + \Psi\,'\pars{t + 1}\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

---

> where $\ds{\Psi}$ is the [Digamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm).
>   With \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}:

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{x - 1 \over \pars{1 - xy}
\ln\pars{xy}}\,\dd x\,\dd y}} =
\lim_{R \to \infty}\int_{0}^{R}
\bracks{-\,{1 \over t + 1} + \Psi\,'\pars{t + 1}}\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{R \to \infty}\bracks{-\ln\pars{R + 1} + \Psi\pars{R + 1} - \Psi\pars{1}} =
\bbx{\gamma}
\end{align}

> Note that $\ds{\Psi\pars{1} = -\gamma}$ and
>   $\ds{\Psi\pars{z} \sim \ln\pars{z} - {1 \over 2z} - {1 \over 12z^{2}}}$ as
>   $\ds{\verts{z} \to\ \infty}$ with $\ds{\verts{\arg{z}} < \pi}$.
>   
>   See [A & S Table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm).

Answer (score 1):

We want use the transformation formula.
\begin{align*}
&U:= \left\lbrace (t,r) \mid t \in (0,1), r \in (t,1) \right\rbrace , V:= (0,1)^2,
\\ &f: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \left( \begin{array}{r}
x\\
y\\
\end{array} \right) \mapsto \frac{x - 1}{(1-xy) \cdot ln(xy)},
\\ &\varphi: U \rightarrow V, \left( \begin{array}{r}
t\\
r\\
\end{array}\right) \mapsto \left( \begin{array}{r}
t/r\\
r\\
\end{array} \right), 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\varphi ^{-1}: V \rightarrow U, \left( \begin{array}{r}
t\\
r\\
\end{array}\right) \mapsto \left( \begin{array}{r}
t \cdot r\\
r\\
\end{array} \right)   
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
D\varphi = \left( \begin{array}{rr}
1/r & -t/r^2\\
0 & 1\\
\end{array}\right),
Det(D\varphi) = \frac{1}{r}. 
\end{align*}

So we can use the transformation.

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x-1}{(1-xy)\cdot ln(xy)} dx \, dy &= \int_0^1 \int_t^1 \frac{(t/r) - 1}{(1-t) \cdot ln(t)} \cdot \frac{1}{r} \, dr \, dt 
\\ &= \int_0^1 \int_t^1 \left( \frac{t}{(1-t) \cdot ln(t)} \cdot \frac{1}{r^2} - \frac{1}{r} \cdot \frac{1}{(1-t) \cdot ln(t)} \right) \, dr \, dt 
\\ &= \int_0^1 \left[ -\frac{1}{r} \cdot \frac{t}{(1-t) \cdot ln(t)} - \frac{ln(r)}{(1-t)\cdot ln(t)} \right]_t^1 \, dt 
\\ &= \int_0^1 \left( \frac{1-t}{(1-t)\cdot ln(t)} + \frac{ln(t)}{(1-t) \cdot ln(t)} \right) \, dt 
\\ &= \int_0^1 \left( \frac{1}{ln(t)} + \frac{1}{1-t} \right) \, dt
\end{align*}

The last integral represented $\gamma$.