# When is $\int_a^b \frac{1}{x}\ln\bigg(\frac{x^3+1}{x^2+1}\bigg)dx=0$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bounds-of-integration

I would like to find positive, distinct, algebraic real numbers $a,b\in \mathbb R^+\cap\mathbb A$ satisfying
$$\int_a^b \frac{1}{x}\ln\bigg(\frac{x^3+1}{x^2+1}\bigg)dx=0$$
Does anyone know of a systematic way to go about solving this problem? Calculating a definite integral is one thing, but solving for the values of its bounds is something that I have no experience with. If we let $a,b$ be numbers satisfying the above relation, then we know that
$$\frac{db}{b}\ln\bigg(\frac{b^3+1}{b^2+1}\bigg)=\frac{da}{a}\ln\bigg(\frac{a^3+1}{a^2+1}\bigg)$$ 
...but this is not useful since the chance of an antiderivative existing is slim.

Can anyone find such $a,b$?

Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3005764/why-does-this-integral-equal-0) question.

**NOTE:** Because the antiderivative of the integrand can be expressed in terms of dilogarithms, the problem is equivalent to finding distinct real algebraic numbers $a,b$ satisfying
$$\frac{\text{Li}_2(-b^3)}{3}+\frac{\text{Li}_2(-b^2)}{2}=\frac{\text{Li}_2(-a^3)}{3}+\frac{\text{Li}_2(-a^2)}{2}$$

Comment: What is $\mathbb{A}$?

Comment: @VonNeumann Algebraic numbers.

Comment: $\ln(\frac{x^3+1}{x^2+1})=\ln(x^2-x+1)-\ln(x^2+1)+\ln(x+1)$ if that is remotely helpful...

Comment: If such $a,b$ do exist then $a$ belongs to $[0;1]$ and $b>1$. The integrand is negative on $[0;1]$ (see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+log((x%5E3%2B1)%2F(x%5E2%2B1))%2Fx )

Comment: Do you have numerics suggesting values of $a$,$b$? It should be possible to use an arbitrary precision package to minimize the square of the integral over all intervals to high precision.

Comment: @asd No, I have not found any values that seem to satisfy this equality.

Comment: Mathematica finds the antiderivative of your integral by $ln((x^3+1)/(x^2+1))=ln(x^3+1)-ln(x^2+1)$ and then writing the argument in a power expansion like $(x^2+1)=(1+i x)*(1-i x)$. Findroot calculates the zero findings for a=0 and b=1.8464.

Comment: @asd It would be useless: given the integrand changes sign, it's easy to prove there are infinitely many distinct *real* $a,b$ such that the integral vanishes. The problem is to find *algebraic* ones. Numerically you have no way to tell the difference.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Nominally useless. There is a detail missing in the comment above that one can minimize the square of the integral starting with some $a$ algebraic so that one finds to high accuracy $b$ which satisfies the integral being zero. If $b$ in fact is algebraic (and satisfies a polynomial of low degree) then it is possible using algdep in Pari/GP to help find this value exactly from the numerics.

Comment: $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\ln\bigg(\frac{x^3+1}{x^2+1}\bigg)dx=\frac{-\pi^2}{72}$$ not sure if this helps

Comment: The fact that the integrand is negative in $(0,1)$ is inconvenient as it deprives usage of the identity $\operatorname{Li}_2(z)+\operatorname{Li}_2(1-z)=\zeta(2)-\log z\log(1-z)$.

Comment: Though if we assume $\exists a,b\in\Bbb A^+$ s.t. $b^2(1+a^2)=1$ then a simple dilogarithm identity gives $$\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac1{(1+a^2)^{3/2}}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2(-a^3)=\frac34\log^2(1+a^2)-3\log(1+a^2)\log a-\frac{\pi^2}4.$$ From [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cbujuvmtoj), we know such $a,b$ exist in $\Bbb R^+$ (and there are in fact two of them). However, I'm not sure what to do with the cubic terms, or how to show that they are even algebraic.

Answer (score 1):

Just an extended comment...

A figure might be helpful.  Using the [Rubi](https://rulebasedintegration.org/) package in *Mathematica* one finds the following:

```
Get["Rubi`"]
integral = Int[(Log[x^3 + 1] - Log[x^2 + 1])/x, {x, a, b}]
```

$$\frac{1}{6} \left(2 \text{Li}_2\left(-a^3\right)-3 \text{Li}_2\left(-a^2\right)\right)+\frac{1}{6} \left(3 \text{Li}_2\left(-b^2\right)-2 \text{Li}_2\left(-b^3\right)\right)$$

as shown by the OP.  A contour plot shows the contours of zero:

```
ContourPlot[integral, {a, -1, 2}, {b, -1, 2}, Contours -> {0},
 PlotPoints -> 100, ContourShading -> None, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Contour plot of level 0]

Comment: Can Mathematica atleast aproximate such numbers $a$ and $b$? I highly believe that $b$ might be $\phi =\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$

Comment: @Zacky Using `FindRoot[integral /. b -> (1 + Sqrt[5])/2, {a, -0.3}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]` *Mathematica* gets `{a -> -0.311511113597363354426784499497}`.

Comment: @Zacky Sorry, I forgot the other root around 0.4:  `sol = FindRoot[integral /. b -> (1 + Sqrt[5])/2, {a, 0.4}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]` which results in `{a -> 0.40710884690013078787253080882807595702108710161649}`.