# Compute the Integral $\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}\ln\left(\frac{x^{4}-2x^{2}+2}{x\left(2-2x+x^{2}\right)}+e^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

This is the original question:
$$I=\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}\ln\left(\frac{2-2x^{2}+x^{4}+2\left(ex^{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}-2x^{2}e^{\frac{1}{x}}+\left(ex^{3x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}}{2x-2x^{2}+x^{3}}\right)dx$$

This is essentially reducible to:
$$I=\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}\ln\left(\frac{x^{4}-2x^{2}+2}{x\left(2-2x+x^{2}\right)}+e^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)dx$$

I thought of using Series Expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ as follows:
$$I=\ln\left(\sqrt{2}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k}\left(\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{x^{4}-2x^{2}+2}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}x\left(2-2x+x^{2}\right)}\right)^{k}dx\right)$$
But I do not know how to continue from here.

The other method I tried was separating the numerator and denominator as follows:

$$\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}\ln\left(2-2x^{2}+x^{4}+2\left(ex^{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}-2x^{2}e^{\frac{1}{x}}+\left(ex^{3x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)dx-\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}\ln\left(2x-2x^{2}+x^{3}\right)dx$$

The integral on the right side can be evaluated and has the following answer (Which I got using CAS):
$$\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}\ln\left(2x-2x^{2}+x^{3}\right)dx=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\ln2}{\sqrt{2}}+\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)\left(\ln\left(4-2\sqrt{2}\right)-3\right)$$

This is a question from a source and I have confirmed that the answer is in the form of $Li_2(x)$ and $\Gamma(x)$.

Comment: Is there a reason you expect this integral to have a closed form answer?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Well as stated in the end, it does have a closed form, but it is not elementary.

Comment: @NinadMunshi How did you arrive at that conclusion? It is not matching numerically.

Comment: You're right, I simplified incorrectly

Comment: At the very least, $e^{1/x}$ won't help you unless you have some Feynman trick in mind. The integral is equivalent to $$\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^1 \log\left(\frac{2x^4-2x^2+1}{x(2x^2-2x+1)}+e^x\right)\frac{dx}{x^2}$$ and there might be some symmetric significance to having a rational polynomial of the form $\frac{f(x^2)}{xf(x)}$ inside the log.

Comment: It is sad  that we do not know the general expression of the coefficients of the Taylor series of the integrand around $x=1$ because the convergence is quite fast.

Comment: What is the source of this integral? The integral without the $e^{1/x}$ and with an $\frac{1}{x}$ appeared here on MSE before.

Comment: @Zacky Well it's posted on a Math Server. And could you link that problem, maybe we could get some hint seeing its solution.

Comment: @Zacky. I also have the feeling it saw the one you mention but I am unable to find it. Do you remember where ?

Comment: @BlackEmperor see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3005764/515527 - the $\frac1x$ is actually outside of the log. Can you also share your math forum? (maybe that can help)

Comment: @BlackEmperor Can you please link the source giving the closed form with $\text{Li}_2(x)$ and $\Gamma(x)$?

Comment: Replace $\color{red}{\large +} e^{1/x}$ by $\color{red}{\large \cdot} e^{1/x}$

Comment: Numerically checking the “$+e^\frac1x$” version, it matches the original problem, so there is probably no “$\cdot e^\frac1x$”.